# how to output mysql table data into an html table without knowing what $row is like phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, sorting

Ok so I'm trying to make a localhost site that has the same base functions as Phpmyadmin, and everything is working other than displaying a table's data.

here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:
[image]

though I'm not sure how to accomplish this. Here is some code to show you what I have now

```
<div class="content">
    <?php $query2 = "SELECT * FROM " . $table; ?>
    <div class="query-class">
        <?php echo $query2; ?>
    </div>
    <h1>
        Tables In <?php echo $db; ?>
    </h1>
    <table>


        <?php
            $columquery = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $table;
            $columresult = mysql_query($columquery);
            while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($columresult)) {
                echo "<th>" . $row3['Field'] . "</th>";
            }
        ?>

        <?php

            $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
            while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
                foreach($row2 as $var) {
                    echo "<tr><td>" . $var . "</td></tr>";   
                }

            }
        ?>
        </table>
</div>
```

Yes yes, I know it's horrible.

Comment: if you want I can screenshot what the result looks like

Comment: You are storing plain text passwords and a hash??

Comment: What happens with this code as is? Where is your issue? Please stop using `mysql_` functions. Use and updated driver. Also depending on how `$table` and `$db` are defined this might be a very dangerous script.

Comment: If you use the `fetch_assoc` style, you could take the array keys for the first row to output the headers. That way you don't have to change anything if your SELECT query specifies specific columns rather than `SELECT *`

Comment: no, the passwords are encrypted but that's not the point I want to be able to use the PHP to read any table

Comment: @user3783243 do you want me to screenshot the result?

Comment: Either describe or show. Passwords shouldn't be encrypted, they should be hashed.

Comment: @user3783243 also the $table and $db are $_GET varibles.

Comment: @Username2020 This is a dangerous script in that case. Use a whitelist so only the tables you want to allow access to are selectable...although I guess listing full DB contents is a security flaw in itself

Comment: @user3783243 it doesn't really matter since the data in the table fine i just want to output the table in the image that you see to a similer HTML5 table. but here: https://imgur.com/T1mh15G

Comment: @user3783243 this is also supposed to be run locally like phpmyadmin and it's supposed to be able to access all of the server.

Comment: the `mysql_query` api is deprecated and has been totally removed from PHP after version 7.The code is vulnerable to exploitation - it would be possibly a wise move to introduce `mysqli` and prepared statements to this process before getting in too much deeper?

Comment: "*The code is vulnerable to exploitation*" — to be honest the code looks suspiciously like malware.  No offense but I've seen a lot of stuff like this on compromised servers. Why else would you possibly want to write it?  If you need phpmyadmin functions just use phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

The other answers use the `mysqli` API while you're using the older, no longer supported `mysql` API. I really recommend upgrading to either `mysqli` or `PDO`, but if you want to stay with `mysql` you can use the following solution:

```
<div class="content">
    <?php $query2 = "SELECT * FROM " . $table; ?>
    <div class="query-class">
        <?php echo $query2; ?>
    </div>
    <h1>
        Tables In <?php echo $db; ?>
    </h1>
    <table>
        <?php
            $shouldOutputHeaders = true;
            $result2 = mysql_query($query2);

            while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
                if ($shouldOutputHeaders) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    foreach (array_keys($row2) as $header) {
                        echo "<th>" . $header . "</th>"; 
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";

                    $shouldOutputHeaders = false;
                }

                echo "<tr>";
                foreach ($row2 as $var) {
                    echo "<td>" . $var . "</td>"; 
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something very ugly like the following. I found it in the garbage. I am not responsable for any use of it:

```
<?php
$db=Db::getConnection(); // singleton
$this->var['result']=$db->query($_POST['query']);

if (isset($this->var['result'])) {
    echo '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" border="1"><tbody>';
    $titles=array_keys(@$this->var['result'][0]);
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($titles as $title)
        echo '<th>'.$title.'</th>';
    echo '</tr>';

    foreach($this->var['result'] as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($row as $cell) {
            echo '<td>'.$cell.'</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</tbody></table>';
}
?>
```

Db is an standard singleton that contains a mysqli private object.
query() contains something like

```
$sql = $this->mysqli->query($query);
$this->lastInsertId = $this->mysqli->insert_id;
$errno = $this->mysqli->connect_errno;
if ($errno === 0) {
    if ($this->mysqli->field_count > 0) {
        while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) $response[] = $row;
        return $response;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

to create the "array of arrays" response. Suitable for the output you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you well, You need mysqli_fetch_row.

```
$q= "SELECT * FROM  table";
$result = $mysqli->query($q)
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        print  ("$row[0], $row[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added some escaping and only queried the database when needed:

```
// Print table tags
echo "<table>";

// Print out records 
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table};");
if($res = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    // Print out columns 
    $columns = array_keys($res[0]);
    echo'<tr><th>'.implode('</th><th>', array_map('htmlspecialchars',$columns).'</th></tr>';
    // Print out table data
    echo'<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>', array_map('htmlspecialchars',$res).'</td></tr>';
} else {
    // IFF there is no data, print out columns
    $q = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM {$table};");
    if($res = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        // Print columns
        echo'<tr><th>'.implode('</th><th>', array_map('htmlspecialchars',$res).'</th></tr>';
    }
}
echo '</table>';
```

Hope this helps,